# MS Access LisBox On_click ItemsSelected is empty

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not certain why this is, but in the Click event, I need to get at the selected item in my Listbox, but when the loop is initialized, there are no selecteditems available.

```
 Private Sub lstUPSCs_Click()
        On Error GoTo Err_lstAttribute_Change

                    Dim strSelect  As String
                    Dim sQuery As String
                    Dim sUPSC As String 
                    Dim itm As Variant


                    For Each itm In Me.lstUPSCs.ItemsSelected
                      strSelect = strSelect & "," & LTrim(RTrim(Mid(lstUPSCs.Column(0, itm), 1, 8)))

                    Next

END SUB
```

Any help with fixing this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a multiselect list box, the following code should return a list of values in the first column (column 0). I would not generally use a click event for a multiselect listbox.

```
For Each itm In Me.lstUNSPSCs.ItemsSelected
  strSelect = strSelect & "," & Me.lstUNSPSCs.Column(0, itm)
Next

strSelect = Mid(strSelect,2)
```

For a listbox without multiselect, the default value of the listbox is the value of the bound column. The above code will not work, but you can simply say:

```
Me.lstUNSPSCs
```

Or

```
Me.lstUNSPSCs.Column(2)
```

Where the number is any valid column number starting from zero.

As an aside, there is no need to LTrim, RTrim - Trim covers both.

Comment: That does not seem to be it at all.  Me.lstUNSPSCs.ItemsSelected.Count = 0. I don't know why.